# Possible to code a SMS function that send sms when email is sent to user?

Tags: php, wordpress, email, web

I am using Directorist plugin and Have Twilio API
function can fetch number from user profile and sent same email content as sms

sms notifications, i need that the same way the system pushs out a email to the user on mutipull events, and the same to the host, and all (most) of these events i want the user/host should receive an sms, to achive this there needs to be an option for users to save thier mobile numbers for sms notifications, and then on each event they should get the sms with dynamic content to their regitredert number.

```
add_action('send_mandrill_email', 'send_sms_notification', 10, 1);

function send_sms_notification($email_data) {
    require_once('wp-content/mu-plugins/twilio-php-sdk/src/Twilio/autoload.php');
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $phone_number = get_user_meta($user_id, 'user[phone]', true);
    if ($phone_number && $email_data['to']) {
        $to = $email_data['to'][0]['email'];
        $subject = $email_data['subject'];
        $body = $email_data['html'];
        $client = new Twilio\Rest\Client('TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID', 'TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN');
        $message = $client->messages->create(
            $phone_number,
            array(
                'from' => 'TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER',
                'body' => "You have received an email from $to with the subject: $subject. Message: $body"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: what is your precise question?  It's possible to use the Twilio SMS API to send arbitrary text to arbitrary mobile phone numbers. But, as you say, you have to get your users to give you their phone numbers ahead of time, and you have to store them somewhere. Probably with update_user_meta(). Budget US$10 per thousand texts in country, and $30 per thousand internationally, and you should be safe. Avoid spam texts, or Twilio will suspend your account.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.